'Expect' header added in automation studio
We are calling a 3rd party API and we noticed that marketing cloud is adding automatically the 'Expect' header when running the code in a script while its not when running the code in a cloud-page.
Also Marketing cloud is not removing the header even we remove it using req.removeHeader('Expect') method.
We are checking it using https://webhook.site/ where you can use endpoints to check the headers and body sent.
The script:
<script runat="server">  
  var url = 'https://webhook.site/d5b12988-2391-42a9-92b8-e73519dd509e'
    
    performDeleteRequest(url)
    
    function performDeleteRequest(url) {
    
        var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
            req.retries = 2;
            req.continueOnError = true;
            req.removeHeader('Expect')
            req.removeHeader('expect')
            req.method = "DELETE";
            req.contentType = "application/json";
            req.encoding = "UTF-8";
    
        var res = req.send();
    
        Platform.Response.Write(url + ' - ' + reqbody + ', status: ' + res.statusCode + ', returnStatus: ' + res.returnStatus )
          
        return res;

       } 
</script>

We may add this code to a code resource and call it from the script that may solve the issue but, does anyone knows how to remove the 'Expect' header?

After oppening a case, the support agent confirmed that the expect header is added when a body is present in the request, not otherwise.
"adding the request body did cause the Expect header to be added.
The Product Team have advised that they will be creating a work item so that they can investigate this further and possibly develop a fix."
So we need to wait, I will try to post here in case there's any update on this issue.
